# Connect a Li-Po battery to solar panel

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell

In this related [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/483169/solar-charger-for-lipo-battery/483223#483223) I just setup a solar charger to a Li-Po battery, but it does not charge the battery at all, since the led in the charger circuit never turns to red color and the battery when tested instead of charged it is a slightly discharged.

I think a phone and the battery itself already as regulator/protection circuitry that would render the charger somewhat redundant.

Would damage occur to the battery (inside a phone) being directly connect to the solar panels? The panels are providing 4.2V/210mA (average).

Answer (score 2):

To charge a battery from a solar panel, you need a battery charger AND a regulator for the solar panel. Solar charge controllers that do both are available (make sure it works for li-ion.

If you don't have a solar MPPT controller, the panel will not operate at the most efficient power point.

Batteries require charging controllers to make sure they are charged correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to PRACTICE caution when using a lithium ion battery. Using words like I think does not go well in terms of safety. Always assume there's no protection circuits. Only move to the next question if the answer is yes.

Secondly check your battery voltage, is it above 2.4V?

Third, remove the load and battery test the output from the B+ and B- terminals, is it around 4.2V?

Fourth, connect the batter if the battery voltage is above 2.4V to the solar charger. Is it charging?

Then apply the load.

Comment: Last time I measured the battery voltage  was around 4.2 V (using the application), besides I have not tested measuring in terminals. When I was using the charger circuit it seemed to be charging since the led says so and the tension using a stripped usb cable was 4 V with 120mA, so I asummed it was charging, but the battery lost 4% of charge in this interval, so I think the amperage is too low to feed the system '(ie. It spent more energy than the provided) so never is gonna to charge.

Comment: Using AC power I  have seen the phone/battery draw up to 560mA, thats way too much for the 120/200mA of the solar charger. I will try to use a standalone 3.7V/380mAh battery.

Comment: _"I think a phone and the battery itself already as regulator/protection circuitry that would render the charger somewhat redundant."_ - yes, the phone already has a charger circuit inside it. The phone expects 5V with a current capacity of at least 100mA (ie. standard USB power). It might not like 6~8V (typical voltage range of a '6V' solar panel).

Comment: Again stop ASSUMING things and be scientific and do the actual measurements. You are using a lithium ion battery don't just assume that charging module is actually working. Do your own testing. If you not willing to do the work and actually conduct your own measurements I recommend you stop what you doing because it can lead to serious harm. If you are not charging the lithium battery with the correct conditions the battery can become unpredictable.